# error while using prepared statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

When I tried to execute this statement, I got the error. I have created an array mem[] which contains table names, and in each table there are two columns with names amt(float(9,2)) and comb(varchar(5)).

```
String table = mem[i];
String x = "all";
String query = "select sum(amt) from" + table +  "where comb = ?";
PreparedStatement pst =con.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, x);

ResultSet a = pst.executeQuery();
```

Error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comb = 'all'' at line 1 
>   what is the error?how can i solve it?
>   i have also tried by replacing ? with all and removing two lines(String x = "all"; and pst.setString(1, x);)

Comment: You're missing spaces around your `table`:  `.. from " + table +   " where ..`

Comment: This is one of those situations where even a cursory glance at a debugger would have shown you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking some spaces.

Change

```
String query = "select sum(amt) from" + table +  "where comb = ?";
```

to

```
String query = "select sum(amt) from " + table +  " where comb = ?";
```

Comment: thanks,but still iam getting some error      com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comb = 'vab'' at line 1

Comment: @BHARATHRAJ Please add a `System.out.println(pst)` before your executeQuery statement and post the output you get.

Comment: not same, iam getting error as mentioned above

Comment: @BHARATHRAJ Did you add it before executing the prepared statement? Which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Add spaces after `FROM` and before `WHERE`:

```
String query = "select sum(amt) from " + table +  " where comb = ?";
```